# Integration testing with QEvent serialization

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, integration-testing, qevent

I want to create integration test toolkit for my gui app.

My app will have 3 modes:

- Normal mode - app just executing and doing what must do
- Record mode - app executing and doing what must do with recording all system events
- Repeat mode - app executing without user participation but with generating user events.

General idea for this tool is recording all system events from user in record mode (such as keyboard typing, mouse clicking) and repeat them in original sequence not from user, but from special unit.

Main problem that I have - is it possible to save `QEvent` with true [spontaneous](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous) flag, without customization to inherited class? In other case I will need write wrapper, that will cast all spontaneous events to inherited class.

Or may be already exist similar tools or qt library for my target?

Comment: Testing gui applications is way more complex than simply recording and replaying events. The test harness must react to what the application is doing as well. If you look at `QEvent`'s internals, it will become apparent how to generate spontaneous events. But, instead of spending thousands of hours creating a half-baked tool, you should look at a tool designed for such purpose, like [froglogic's squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/).

Comment: @KubaOber really, I forgot about this solution! Thank you very much, I will try this!